# Type Level Literals - Cannot use differently typed parameters in binary function

Tags: haskell

Playing with [Type Level Literals](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeNats) as a way to discriminate non empty container values (as with phantom types) using a Maybe like type.

This works well. (required GHC >= 7.6.1)

But trying to define a binary function (eq)

```
eq :: (Eq a) => TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a -> TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a -> Bool
```

that admits different groups of values, signals a compile error when it is used:

Couldn't match type `"Just"' with`"Nothing"'

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs, FlexibleInstances #-} 

import GHC.TypeLits

data TMaybe :: Symbol -> * -> * where
  TNothing  :: TMaybe "Nothing" a
  TJust :: a -> TMaybe "Just" a

nonEmpty :: Maybe a -> TMaybe "Just" a
nonEmpty (Just x) = TJust x
nonEmpty Nothing = error "invalid nonEmpty data"

-- this fromJust rejects TNothing at compile time  
fromJust :: (sym ~ "Just") => TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a -> a
fromJust (TJust x) = x

tmbToMaybe :: TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a -> Maybe a
tmbToMaybe TNothing = Nothing
tmbToMaybe (TJust x) = Just x

mbToTNothing Nothing = TNothing

mbToTJust (Just x) = TJust x

instance Eq a => Eq (TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a) where
     TNothing == TNothing = True
     TJust x == TJust y = x == y
     _ == _ = False    -- useless, equal types required

instance Ord a => Ord (TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a) where
     compare TNothing TNothing = EQ
     compare (TJust x) (TJust y) = Prelude.compare x y
     compare TNothing _ = LT   -- useless, equal types required
     compare _ TNothing = GT   -- useless, equal types required

instance  Functor (TMaybe (sym :: Symbol))  where
    fmap _ TNothing       = TNothing
    fmap f (TJust a)      = TJust (f a)

instance  Monad (TMaybe "Just") where
    (TJust x) >>= k      = k x

    (TJust _) >>  k      = k

    return            = TJust
    fail _              = error "can't fail to TNothing"

--------------------------

-- defining eq to admit parameter types with different symbol

eq :: (Eq a) => TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a -> TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a -> Bool
eq TNothing TNothing = True
eq (TJust x) (TJust y) = x == y
eq _ _ = False

---------------------------

-- Test

main = do
        print $ fromJust $ TJust (5::Int)   -- type-checks
        -- print $ fromJust TNothing   -- as expected, does not type-check

        -- print $ TNothing == TJust (5::Int)  -- as expected, does not type-check, types required equal at function def.
        print $ TNothing `eq` TJust (5::Int)   -- does not type-check either
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, your type

```
eq :: (Eq a) => TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a -> TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a -> Bool
```

demands that both arguments have the same type, so of course the compiler will reject an attempt to compare a `TMaybe "Nothing" a` and a `TMaybe "Just" a`.

If you change the type to

```
eq :: (Eq a) => TMaybe (sym :: Symbol) a -> TMaybe (sym1 :: Symbol) a -> Bool
```

it compiles and

```
TNothing `eq` TJust (5::Int)
```

evaluates to `False`. (You then need to explicitly determine the type of `TNothing`s in many places, though.)

Comment: thanks, with the kind stuff cluttering the type, I did not pay attention to the ''sym'' variable